# what do these lines do in assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm, tasm

I am quite new to assembly. I am always confused by the numbers
Can someone please help me ? I am using TASM... so 8066 assembler
Is there any good reference that I can use?

```
SCREEN_CLEARER:
mov ax,1720h
mov cx,2000
mov bx,0
L2:
mov es:[bx],ax
add bx,2
loop L2
ret
```

I don't really get what 1720h, 2000 are. I also not quite sure how to read move es:[bx],ax

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like DOS-code, trying to fill the (text) screen buffer or so ..., IIRC `ax` would be character (0x20 == ' ' == space) combined with the text attributes (0x17 == foreground/background color).

The 2000 would be 80x25 ;)

`es` would for this purpose point to the screen buffer.

```
L2:
mov es:[bx],ax
add bx,2
loop L2
```

moves the character and attribute (in `ax`) into each word from `es:[0]` for 2000 words (== 2 bytes) until `cx` becomes 0 (that's the meaning of the `loop` opcode).

Comment: yes indeed. the code comes from here. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/assembly/threads/117744. so the 2nd line is printing white space? and there's background color? thanks.

Comment: oh the display is 80x25. thats true. what is 1720h then?

Comment: @JohnWong: I wrote it, it's one byte for the character (' ' == 0x20) and one for the attribute (0x17 is likely light gray on black or so, but frankly I don't remember the values and they would depend on the BIOS/system).